# Mouse pointer dissapears while typing - UBUNTU 18.04 LTS

Tags: 18.04, keyboard, shortcut-keys, mouse, mouse-pointer

I was playing with my keyboard shortcuts using various FN function and I realised that my mouse pointer now disappears when I type and it doesn't come back unless I move the mouse.

This happens in text editors like IntelliJ IDEA, Gedit, etc. and also in Terminal. Doesn't happen in browsers for some reason.

I've already switched the 'Disable While Typing' setting in Tweaks but it's still doing it.

Any ideas?